# How to automate SQL query to get row count of all tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

We need to automate the SQL row count, as of now we are using an Excel formula to fill `count(*)` query to all tables and copying it and pasting in Oracle SQL Developer and running all at once.

So, what I am looking for: is there any way to get automated by using Python or any programming language which directly connects to a database by asking necessary inputs and get all the process done by itself and get me row count for each table without involving me or any process said above.

Comment: It can be done, but what's the need?

Comment: I am with jarlh here; why would you want to do this? It doesn't seem to make much sense to get a list of all tables and their row counts. Anyway, the fastest and easiest approach would be to get the approximate row counts per last table analisys via `SELECT owner, table_name, num_rows FROM dba_tables`.